# Datatables issue with grouping all columns in 1 row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have the table and created 1 row using colspan, next row with my data.
[Example in codepen](https://codepen.io/paulch/pen/vQRoLX)

But datatables library doesn't work and I have some issue in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined
>        at Ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js:24)
>        at O (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">TESTTEST</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Maybe this feature is not supported by Datatables, or this is some bugs. Or, maybe, someone can help me to resolve this. It'll be great. Or some small advice.

Answer (score 0):

Colspan is not supported on Datatables. However you can use this workaround:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="6">TESTTEST</td>
  <td style="display: none;"></td>
  <td style="display: none;"></td>
  <td style="display: none;"></td>
  <td style="display: none;"></td>
  <td style="display: none;"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yeah, this solution fixes some problem, but I want to do something like that https://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/gaGBZz, and when I'm sorting these rows they are swapping with each other, but I want to https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html with expand/collapse child rows. Do you know something?
Your solution fixed the previous issue, but it's not solution what I'm searching for.